# suggestions are not sorting on frequency using comparatorFreq=freq(Not working)

Tags: sorting, solr, frequency, spell-checking, search-suggestion

I have created 2 nodes having **2 shards** in `Solr`. I am doing **spell correction technique**. I want to **sort** the **suggestions** of **query(abple)** on the basis on **frequency**. By **default**, it is **sorting** on **score**(Levenshtein Distance).

I added `<str name="comparatorClass">freq</str>` in **solr.SpellCheckComponent** of **solrconfig.xml**. But still, it is **not** working.

**Current suggestions are sorted on score (Not required):**

```
"suggestion":[{
            "word":"apple",
            "freq":23},
          {
            "word":"ample",
            "freq":5},
          {
            "word":"abele",
            "freq":3},
          {
            "word":"able",
            "freq":176}}]
```

**Require suggestions to sort on frequency (Required):**

```
"suggestion":[{
            "word":"able",
            "freq":176}},
          {
            "word":"apple",
            "freq":23},
          {
            "word":"ample",
            "freq":5},
          {
            "word":"abele",
            "freq":3}}]
```

**Configurations files:**

**solrconfig.xml:**

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpellCi</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">gram_ci</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">0</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">2</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.9</float>
      <str name="comparatorClass">freq</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">gram_ci</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">25</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">100000000</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">25</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">50</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">50</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

**Schema.xml:**

```
<field name="gram_ci" type="textSpellCi" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

</fieldType><fieldType name="textSpellCi" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="5" minShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
</analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="5" minShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem but it worked for me making the change you mentioned:

```
<str name="comparatorClass">freq</str>
```

You may not have restarted your solr instance. Try doing that first.

Comment: Confirmed this works when added to the searchComponent spellchecker setup, thank you (Solr 7.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Try after adding this param to your search handler:

`<str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>`

Comment: Can you share your config?

Comment: I want to do spell/query correction functionality. I have 49 GB indexed data where I have applied spellchecker. I want to do same as Google - "did you mean".
Example - If any user types any question/query which might be misspell or wrong typed. I need to give them suggestion like "Did you mean".
Is Solr best for it?